# New system build powers on, immediately power off

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I have a home server I'm building that is immediately powering off after I turn it on. The motherboard is an Intel S2600CP4, I have installed two Xeon processors and 64 GB of RAM in 4 16GB DIMMs. The power supply is an EVGA 1000G. When I turn it on with the front power button, various lights come on on the motherboard that make it look like it's starting a self-check routine, but in about 1 to 1.5 seconds it immediately powers off again. I did some research that told me the power supply has to be EPS12V (as opposed to ATX), and this power supply claims it "Complies with EPS 12V v2.91". There are no audible beeps from the system board or the power supply at any point. Is this power supply actually compatible? If so, what could the problem be?

Comment: [Manual of the MoBo](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/g54899001_s2600cp_p4000cp_sg_rev14.pdf), page 179f: "During the system boot process, the BIOS executes a number of platform configuration processes, each of which is assigned a specific hex POST code number" - have you tried to decode that? I'm not sure if it will tell us much, but perhaps the code leads to the reason.

Comment: That happened to me once, and it was an issue with one of the memory slots. Try taking out all but one DIMM. If it still doesn't work, switch that with another DIMM (in a different slot) and try starting it again.

Comment: I don't have any POST code displays available to decode. Swapping memory out had no effect.